# Windows cannot access SMB server, unless I have added the crentials to the Credential Manager

Tags: windows, network-shares, samba

When I type `\\smb_server_name` in File Explorer, it shows that says Windows cannot access the server like below. But if I add the ID/password for that server in Credential Manager -> Windows Credentials, then doing the same thing opens the server. My question is, if it does not know the credential, why doesn't it show the ID/password dialogue instead of saying that Windows cannot access it. Is this some sort of misconfiguration of the SMB server, or the Windows client? Or is this the intended behaviour from Microsoft?

[image]

Comment: Does the server say that your authentication attempt failed, or that it _succeeded_? (Windows normally tries your 'local' credentials first, only prompting if those fail.) What OS is the SMB server running? If it's using Samba – have you tried just restarting smbd (especially if it has been upgraded recently)?

Comment: @user1686 The server is Ubuntu 20.04. The ID of the Ubuntu server and the Windows client are different. How do I know what the server says? I looked up the log file at `/var/log/samba` and it had lots of files that included clients' names. I deleted all files and restarted smbd, and then try to access the server from Windows (with no credentials saved). Windows of course failed, and smbd did create a log file with the name of the client, but the length is 0 so there was no log. "log.smbd" just contained two entries about starting the Samba service.